# How to implement navigation in complex .Net Maui app

Tags: navigation, maui

I am planning on making a quite complex application using .Net Maui, but what I've seen so far regarding navigation seems to be quite a train wreck because it's not really flexible and clumsy and - at least for me - works only for small apps with only a few pages. So what I would like to do is the following:
There should be a main page, below that there are several sections like an admin section, a section for basic data, etc. Below that there are dedicated pages for e.g. user management, role management and from there the user can then navigate to an edit form. So it looks like this

```
    Admin
        User mgmt
            User list and editor
        Role mgmt
            Role list and editor
    Basic data
        ...
    ...
...
```

So far I tried to achieve this by only adding `ShellContent` blocks to my AppShell.xaml file, but then the flyout just gets cluttered with way too many items. Using dedicated Shells for each section, e.g. Admin, also does not work, because somehow I cannot replace AppShell with a more specialized one. Adding menu bars to Admin also does not work very well, because back navigation does not work properly.
Is there anything I could do to make a decent, real-life flyout menu with for example expandable sub-items?

Comment: There is a way - yes. Tab gesture recognizer on item1 (lets call it header), that shows/hides item2,3,4 (lets call it sub-items). Or menu items for each page. Or some TabBars. Also (my opinion), you are wasting time and energy, to implement your custom idea, that may or may not work, and your users may or may not like, instead of using something fast to implement, that everyone is used to. Think about it...